# Microsoft Edge Webview Issues

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, remote-desktop, webview2, imanage

I am trying to install an application on my remote PC using the Windows installer.

The application requires Webview2 to be installed on my PC, and I have it already installed. However the installer tells me that it is not installed. Where do I go from here?

This is what the installer tells me when I try to install the application:

[image]

When I check the Add or Remove Programs, it shows that Edge Webview2 is installed, so why is the installer not detecting it? (I downloaded the standalone installer from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to install the Edge WebView2 successfully then there is no issue with the Edge WebView2.

Actually, the issue is with your iManage app installer which is not able to detect the WebView 2 installation.

There could be various reasons why it is not able to find the installation.

1. You could try to restart the machine after installing the Edge WebView2 and then install the iManege and see if it finds the installation properly.
2. You could try to check whether the version of the WebView2 you installed is compatible with the iManage app. If not, you need to install the supported version of WebView2.

There are documents from iManage, you could check to get more information on this.

1. [Installing Microsoft Edge WebView2 runtime](https://docs.imanage.com/wdw-install-help/10.5.0/en/Installing_Microsoft_Edge_WebView2_runtime.html)
2. [Microsoft Edge WebView2 integrated with iManage Work Desktop for Windows](https://docs.imanage.com/wdw-custom-help/10.6.0/en/Microsoft_Edge_WebView2_integrated_with_iManage_Work_Desktop_for_Windows.html)

If the issue persists, you could raise this issue to the [iManage community](https://imanage.com/community/community/) or [iManage support](https://imanage.com/community/support/).

They could provide you with proper guidance on how to install the iManage app.